# Curl timeout when downloading xml

Tags: php, xml, curl

So, I try to get xml-file with curl from url. Thing is, file is generated on demand via script, which takes up to 80-100 seconds and so my curl is falling off with timeout error.

url looks something like this:

```
https://domain/mancgi/report?params&out=xml
```

I tried to set `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` and `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT`, and also `set_time_limit()` for script itself(which works fine), but nothing's changed - still timeout.

Curl code looks like this:

```
set_time_limit(1000);
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300); 
$xml = curl_exec($curl);
```

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: You have need to increase script time execution limit from server setting.

Comment: What kind of timeout are you geting and how do you know that? Provide details please

Comment: Execution time is overrided by set_time_limit() according to phpinfo(), but even if it's not - by default it's set to 180 seconds, which is enough by itself.

Comment: I get timeout after about 60 seconds and I can guarantee that's not enough. If any other detail is needed - I would gladly provide it

Comment: Can you be sure the remote service isn't what's timing out? does the remote service work ok using curl from command line?

Comment: Can you directly access the xml by opening the link in a browser?

Comment: @Pushpesh Yes, I can, every time works like a charm. A two-minutes-long charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you may be hitting the default_socket_timeout in the php.ini which is 60 seconds by default.

Try changing and see if it works. If not, try this instead.

```
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
```

Doing this will use wrappers which you can read about here: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php

And you will need to also ensure that the required wrappers for use by file_get_contents are enabled in php.ini (which are usually enable so you should be ok, but just check to make sure).

Using that may bypass the timeout you are experiencing if the timeout is enforced by CURL and remember to adjust the default_socket_timeout in php.ini FROM 60 SECONDS to something else which i believe may be your problem

**The INI Settings To Check**

http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php

Comment: @user1834735, @VBAssassin Sorry, did you mean `file_get_contents()`? Because I know no functions by the name of `get_file_content()` and my Google doesn't know them either. And `file_get_contents()` won't do the trick. After several-hour-brainstorm with most of the office we've come to conclusion that this problem is a rare combination of Apache configuration, php.ini directives and bad luck mostly so we're going with Pearl this time and I'm closing the question. But thanks to all of you for your time anyway, you all were actually really helpful.

Comment: Pearl? You mean Perl? ;) corrected the typo. "After several-hour-brainstorm with most of the office" Really? Over something like this? :/ Is there no senior PHP developer as a senior should have known all the places to look for this kind of problem. Good luck :)

Comment: Yeah, Perl, mah bad. And yep, really, over something like this. First, we actually don't have a senior PHP developer - REALLY - and second, it was a very boring day so this was kind of entertaiment for all of us :) Thanks anyway, good luck to you too.

Comment: Haha, can't get fairer than that ;) Intrigued as to why perl? I did one quick script in perl years ago - and now when i look over it i don't know how the hell i wrote it! I know call it the spaghetti language :D

Comment: Well, that according to my supervisor was a simple solution. "Hell with it, here's a perl-script that I have written in the last five minutes, it doesn't give a heck about Apache config and whatsoever, it just downloads this file and stores it whereever you need. Have a nice day." - almost exatly his words, swear. So it's not my place to argue with him - I just move on with my business :)

Comment: Haha, can't argue with that ><

Answer (score 0):

Is URL a GET request? If so try

```
$xml = get_file_content($url);
```

Comment: There's no such function in php